# Magento - Create a CMS page for new customers to sign up

Tags: forms, magento, content-management-system

I need to create a page in Magento 1.6.2 with a form to sign up for an account.

However I am not being given access to any of the sites files, so I need to be able to do it purely through the backend.

Probably with a CMS Page and getting template files, using {{block type=""}} (It's been a while since I've worked with Magento so I've forgotten a bit)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, is it even possible?

Comment: No I'm afraid that doesn't seem to be working, nothing is showing up

Comment: Try this, it works on 1.7.0.2 - `{{block type ="core/template" template="persistent/customer/form/login.phtml" }}`

Comment: Ah great, that works. I think I'm going to call this the best solution given the limitations I've got, Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in 1.6.2 and 1.7.0.2

```
{{block type ="customer/form_login" template="persistent/customer/form/login.phtml" }}
```